# Larger inline plots in Jupyter using Matlab kernel

Tags: matlab, jupyter-notebook

Running Jupyter with a Python kernel, one can adjust the dimensions of inline plots using e.g. `plt.subplots(..., figsize=(...))`. Using the Matlab IDE, the size of plots can be adjusted with `set(gcf, 'position', [...])`. But is there a way to adjust the size of inline plots in Jupyter using a Matlab kernel?

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen at https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Calysto/matlab_kernel/blob/master/matlab_kernel.ipynb:

[image: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Calysto/matlab_kernel/blob/master/matlab_kernel.ipynb]

You can use MAGIC! eg：

```
%plot -s 200,150
```